# Apache 2.4 .htaccess - deny access to a dynamic path excluding traffic from my IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to deny access to a dynamic generated path (not a directory): `/admin` from within the .htaccess using mod_rewrite module. I want this roule to be handled for each request except requests made from a specyfic IP.
The below example works fine with Apache 2, however for some reason it doesn't work in my production environment (Apache 2.4).

```
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^82.11\.97\.176$
    RewriteRule ^(admin) http://example.com [R=302,L]
```

I would be very grateful for your help. Thanks!

Comment: 1. one of the dots (`.`) in the ip address is not escaped. Why not? 2. what is `payu.express`? 3. why are you trying to capture the string "admin" in the pattern?

Comment: Are you sure that the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files is enabled? You generally should prefer to place such rules directly in the http servers host configuration. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and the _really_ slow the server down. They are only offered as a last option for those who absolutely do _not_ have access to the host configuration.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha - the unescaped dot is a slip, however it should not be crutial (as far as I know). The URL is and example redirect... I wan't any path that includes the world admin to be redirected - that's why I've used a pattern

Comment: OK, all fine. That dot _should_ be escaped, though indeed it would match without. The thing is it matches _more_ than just that address, so theoretically you might have wrong positives. The pattern should be `^admin` without brackets. Since you do not use the captured string in your rule there is no sense in capturing it. But the most important question still is unanswered: _is the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files enabled at all_ ?

Comment: The interpretation of .htaccess is enabled. I forgot to mention that under production environment all requests that include `admin` in it's URL are redirected (including those made from my IP).

Comment: Hm, maybe some form of implicit proxy in between, so that the actual ip address is off? First check: compare the ip addresses in your http servers access log file. If that does not offer new insights, then you will have to enable rewrite logging in your http servers host configuration to be able to see in detail what is going on inside the rewrite engine. You should be able to see exactly what ip address the conditional pattern is applied to and why it does/does not match.